# Apache CSV: Parsing quoted data with separator

Tags: java, apache-commons-csv

I have CSV data like this (fully quoted, comma separated, records finishes with ';':

```
"595010","MHD-10 SKIBUS Usti n.L., Divadlo - Telnice, Zadni Telnice","25013891","A","A","0","0","0","0","","","","","23122017","11032018","1","1";
```

I configured my Apache CSV parser with:

```
CSVFormat.newFormat(',')
    .withQuoteMode(QuoteMode.ALL)
    .withQuote('\"')!!
    .withRecordSeparator(';')
```

But when I am trying to parse it, I am getting error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: IOException reading next record: java.io.IOException: (line 1) invalid char between encapsulated token and delimiter
```

when parser processes ';'. 
What am I doing wrong?
Thank you for answers

Comment: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/apidocs/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVFormat.html#withRecordSeparator-java.lang.String-   if you see this it say it only support /n /r as record separators.

Comment: Yes, commons-csv cannot parse this additional end-of-line-character right now.